# Interpolation with tempdisagg package in R

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-interpolation

I have a daily frequency data of stock prices with some missing values and I want to interpolate them using the package tempdisagg.  Does anyone have an example of interpolation with this package?

I am using this code:

```
my_td \<- td(merged_df, High \~ year(Date), to = 1, method = "litterman-minrss", conversion = "mean")
```

But when I run the code R crashes.

I just want to fill the missing values of missing values using the method litterman-minrss.

Comment: See helpfile `?tempdisagg::td` for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use the \`td\` command from the \`tempdisagg\` package to disaggregate monthly data into daily data frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417660/how-can-i-use-the-td-command-from-the-tempdisagg-package-to-disaggregate-mon)